# Devtools: check deletes Rdocumentation for RData

Tags: package, dataset, devtools

I am running a check by devtools for my newly created package. I have a default dataset in RData format (macroKZ.Rdata). I created .R file(macroKZ.R) for it and .Rd file (macroKZ.Rd), but when I run devtools:check(manual=true), the command deletes my .Rd file for the dataset and this become a warning. Could you please help to fix it to check the whole package and create Pdf manual?

```
> library(AFR)
> devtools::check(manual=TRUE)
ℹ Updating AFR documentation
ℹ Loading AFR
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing NAMESPACE
Deleting macroKZ.Rd
```